# Bootstrap 4 side bar multi level - collapse show hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a vertical Nav with bootstrap 4 with 2 levels of lists. When i click one drop down the other drop down is not closing.

Please check the issue here.
https://jsfiddle.net/thilanka/cr0Lfmd1

```
  <ul class="nav flex-column flex-nowrap">
             <li class="nav-item drop">
                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" > sub menu 1</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <ul class="flex-column pl-2 nav">

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link collapsed py-1" href="#submenu1sub1" data-toggle="collapse" >sub 11</a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="submenu1sub1" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <ul class="flex-column nav pl-4">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o"></i> Daily
                                            </a>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>           
             <li class="nav-item drop">
                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu4" data-toggle="collapse" >sub menu 2</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="submenu4" aria-expanded="false">
                        <ul class="flex-column pl-2 nav">

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link collapsed py-1" href="#submenu1sub3" data-toggle="collapse" >sub 22</a>
                                <div class="collapse" id="submenu1sub3" aria-expanded="false">
                                    <ul class="flex-column nav pl-4">
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-clock-o"></i> Daily
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="nav-item">
                                            <a class="nav-link p-1" href="#">
                                                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I need to create a bootstrap 4 side bar with 2 levels of menu.

Comment: use bootstrap accordion https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example

Comment: i'm using this as a side bar menu. so it wont help,

Comment: you can change the css of the accordion to make it look like accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if its possible using *Bootstrap*'s own API but you can achieve this using little bit of `jQuery`:

**Code:**

```
$('#my-nav>.nav-item').click(function(e) {
  $('.nav-item').not(this).each(function(a, b){
    $(b).find('div.collapse.show').each(function(x, y) {
        $(this).removeClass('show');
    });
  });
});
```

Make sure to give your parent `ul` the id of `my-nav`. The idea is to remove the `show` class from all `div` children except for the one item which is clicked.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwek0asj/1/)

Comment: Thanks, can you add an animation to it

Comment: i want to add a slide from left animation.

Comment: can u link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
      <div class="">
        <div class="nav nav-pills" id="headingOne">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              sub menu 1
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Orders</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Customers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <div class="" id="headingTwo">
          <h2 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              sub menu 2
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
          <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Orders</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Customers</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used **[Accordion example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/collapse/)** of Bootstrap and just added nav to it and removed some of the classes. 
Hope it'll help

Comment: can you add nested menu under sub menus, like in the original example of OP?